# Is en_UK an illegal locale?

Tags: php, zend-framework, locale

So far I had always used 'en_UK' for British English. Today I got an error when using it with Zend Framework because the locale is not included in the long list of recognized locales.

Here's just a short extract of that list:

```
'ee_GH' => true, 'ee_TG' => true, 'ee'    => true, 'el_CY' => true, 'el_GR' => true,
'el'    => true, 'en_AS' => true, 'en_AU' => true, 'en_BE' => true, 'en_BW' => true,
'en_BZ' => true, 'en_CA' => true, 'en_GB' => true, 'en_GU' => true, 'en_HK' => true,
'en_IE' => true, 'en_IN' => true, 'en_JM' => true, 'en_MH' => true, 'en_MP' => true,
'en_MT' => true, 'en_NA' => true, 'en_NZ' => true, 'en_PH' => true, 'en_PK' => true,
'en_SG' => true, 'en_TT' => true, 'en_UM' => true, 'en_US' => true, 'en_VI' => true,
'en_ZA' => true, 'en_ZW' => true, 'en'    => true, 'eo'    => true, 'es_AR' => true,
'es_BO' => true, 'es_CL' => true, 'es_CO' => true, 'es_CR' => true, 'es_DO' => true,
```

As you can see, there are all kinds of territories with English language and there is also an entry 'en_GB' which I assume stands for Great Britain... but there is no 'en_UK'. Is that just a 'bug' in Zend Framework or is there another reason for that?

Comment: Zend's locale index confirms that en_GB is English/Great Britain, but I don't see an en_UK so my guess would be en_GB is preferred. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.appendix.html

Comment: Official ISO page mentions GB as a valid code, but not UK: http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm

Comment: @PHPMyCoder: Yes, that's what the answers already show!

Comment: In the locale world `uk` stands for Ukraine, not the UK :)

Comment: @Ilya, that I had to look up.  I believe the Ukrainian language is uk but Ukraine itself is UA, i.e. uk_UA.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The correct country code is `en_GB`. Locales use ISO 3166-1 for country codes. The [wikipedia writeup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Naming_and_code_construction) includes:

> The codes are chosen, according to the ISO 3166/MA, "to reflect the
>   significant, unique component of the country name in order to allow a
>   visual association between country name and country code".[7] For this
>   reason, common components of country names like "Republic", "Kingdom",
>   "United", "Federal" or "Democratic" are normally not used for deriving
>   the code elements. As a consequence, for example, the United Kingdom
>   is officially assigned the alpha-2 code GB rather than UK, based on
>   its official name "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern
>   Ireland" (although UK is reserved on the request of the United
>   Kingdom).

Comment: Ah, an even better explanation.

Comment: Then why is the 'US' valid?

Comment: @qdot  Those appear to be guidelines that were used, rather than hard rules.  To me 'US' appears to be a reasonable short code for the States.  Speaking as a Brit, I think 'GB' is a better fit than 'UK' which seems very bland - but that's just my opinion.

Comment: The only other possible short code for the United States would be SA (dropping United) but that's taken -- Saudi Arabia and South Africa fought over it. AM is for Armenia, who can't take AR because of Argentina. So we had to settle for US.

Comment: Or you could have settled for AA.

Comment: What is the case of Serbia, his ISO code is RS meaning Republic of Serbia (Republika Srbija)? 
courious...

Comment: @GolezTrol You, mate, have made my day for that! Thank you for the much needed laugh. Not that I don't have many laughs in a day - but it was a good one! As for Martin I'm mixed on that one. I've always preferred the UK but I don't know why. I guess it's a style preference type of thing. Anyway I was thinking it was *en_GB* but I could not remember for sure and I wanted to verify it. Ta.

Comment: Weird. So what do they speak in 'and Northern Ireland'?

Answer (score 21):

It is indeed a common (?) mistake. en_UK is wrong. The ISO country code for the UK is GB, making the language tag en_GB.

Comment: But I see it all over the place! Not even the PHP manual is free of en_UK's.

Comment: There are no ISO locales. There are [ISO language codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639), [ISO country codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166), and [IETF language tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCP_47). But I guess you mean [C/POSIX locale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale#POSIX-type_platforms).

Comment: I referred to the language tag, which is built up from (in this case) two ISO codes. The actual problem in this case, is indeed that the country codes (ISO 3166-1 alpha-2) do GB instead of UK. UK is reserved (on request of the UK), but is invalid to use.  But I wanted my answer to merely point out the concrete error (wrong code vs right code) instead of being a history lesson. Nevertheless, it shouldn't be wrong, so I changed that sentence a little bit.

Comment: The language tag would be `en-GB`, the POSIX locale is `en_GB`. Yes, I am nitpicking. But I believe ZF doesn't provide any functions to convert between the two, so you'll likely end up with the *invalid* `lang="en_GB"` in your HTML.

Comment: ZF does consider both en-GB and en_GB as legal locale strings.

Comment: @markus But the HTML standards do not consider language tags with underscore as "legal", they must be IETF BCP 47 codes in "lang" attributes of HTML tags. Yes, I'm commenting 8 years later...

Answer (score 7):

> Imperfect implementations
>
> Starting in 1985, ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes have been used in the
>   Domain Name System as country code top-level domains (ccTLDs). The
>   Internet Assigned Numbers Authority currently assigns the ccTLDs
>   mostly following the alpha-2 codes, but with a few exceptions.[9] For
>   example, the United Kingdom, whose alpha-2 code is GB, uses .uk
>   instead of .gb as its ccTLD, as UK is currently exceptionally reserved
>   in ISO 3166-1 on the request of the United Kingdom.

According to wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2.

So apparently it's an old thing that has stuck or something like that.

EDIT: martin clayton found a better answer.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot simply invent locales! They are already defined. So "en-gb" is British English, whereas "en-us" is American English. If you use "en-uk", you are just making up a code.

As to why the official code is "en-gb" and not "en-uk", I think basically because there is no such thing as United Kingdom English. The language variant is British. Note that the difference between Great Britain and the United Kingdom is:

UK = GB + Northern Ireland

So by naming the variant "en-UK" it's as if you are saying that you want to include the way they speak in Northern Ireland within this category. But why would you want to do that? From a linguistic perspective it makes no sense, as Northern Ireland English is closer to Irish English (en-IE) than British English.

Comment: I think this answer is interesting (from a linguistic perspective :-) Would be interesting to hear the rationale from those who downvoted it. (even though it doesn't add the full background as in the @martin_clayton answer)

Comment: @Per: it's linguistically interesting, it just happens to be wrong because in the context "GB" is the ISO country code for the whole of the United Kingdom (counter-intuitively including NI), not just for England, Wales and Scotland. No doubt there are people in NI who'd prefer the ISO country code to be UK.

Comment: @SteveJessop Interesting. That's probably why the UK uses .uk as their TLD; it would be more ISO-correct to use .gb but it doesn't really reflect the reality on the ground where the country is really "United Kingdom of Great Britain AND Northern Ireland"...

Answer (score 4):

the correct country code in ISO 3166 for the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland is for some reason "GB", so the locale code should be en_GB, and not en_UK as noted [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/iso-3166-1_decoding_table.htm#GB).

en_GB is also used by glibc, gnome, kde, etc

Also i like the fact that many previous bug fixes in opensource projects are related to this like in [apache http 1.3](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29517) and [roundcube project](http://trac.roundcube.net/ticket/1485993)