# How to get the current language in Android?

Tags: android, local

In my Android phone language setting, I set the language to the **English(United Kingdowm)**.

And I use the following code to get the language:

```
Log.d(TAG,"getDisplayLanguage = " + Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage());
Log.d(TAG,"getLanguage = " + Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
Log.d(TAG,"Resources.getLanguage = " + Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage());
Log.d(TAG,"getResources.getLanguage = " + getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
```

And the log show like the following:

```
getDisplayLanguage = English
getLanguage = en
Resources.getLanguage = en
getResources.getLanguage = en_GB
```

It did not show `Local.UK`.

Did I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the answer in [Is en_UK an illegal locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296262/is-en-uk-an-illegal-locale)

The correct country code is en_GB. Locales use ISO 3166-1 for country codes. The wikipedia writeup includes:

> The codes are chosen, according to the ISO 3166/MA, "to reflect the
>   significant, unique component of the country name in order to allow a
>   visual association between country name and country code".[7] For this
>   reason, common components of country names like "Republic", "Kingdom",
>   "United", "Federal" or "Democratic" are normally not used for deriving
>   the code elements. As a consequence, for example, the United Kingdom
>   is officially assigned the alpha-2 code GB rather than UK, based on
>   its official name "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern
>   Ireland" (although UK is reserved on the request of the United
>   Kingdom).

Thats not my answer, it's the answer from the linked post. Just in case the linked answer won't be available at some time.

Answer (score 1):

if you check Locale.UK in code it is en_GB

http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en-GB/

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't return like that what try you trying to get in Log massage.
Log massage will print only string value. But Locale is a class and UK is(public static final Locale UK = null;) a variable in the class. which return the same string value u r getting in Log massage.